# Bootstrap Modal not responding

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a modal that I used from a previous site where it works fine. Difference is this modal will only appear in IE9 only to direct users to a better browser. I was able to test it with just a alert and works fine.

However, for some reason, when I transfer the code I did for a previous site to this new site, the Modal isn't responding and to one point is not showing on the site.

When I try close the "Close" button, it will just refresh the page. I am not sure why and when I close the "X" button, it does not work either.

The code is inserted in a coldfusion file and I am not sure if it causing conflict or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I did for the modal. ie-only detects whether it is IE9 or not:

```
<!---<div class="ie-only" style="overflow-y:hidden;">
        <div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" aria-hidden="false" style="display:block; padding-right:17px;">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-md custom-height-modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:##428bca">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-miss="modal">x</button>
                        <h3 class="modal-header" style="background-color:##428bca; text-align:center">Attention</h3>                        
                    </div><!---Modal-Header Div--->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p style="text-align:center">You are using an outdated browser.<br /> <br /> <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a> to better experience this site.</p>
                    </div><!---Modal-Body Div--->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a></p>
                    </div><!---Modal-Footer Div--->
                </div><!---Modal-Content Div--->
            </div><!---Custom Height Div--->
        </div><!---Modal Fade in Div--->
    </div><!---Start of Modal Div--->               
    <!--End of Modal container--> --->
     <!---<script>
            $(function(){
                $('##myModal').modal('show');
            }
          </script>  
                <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>--->
```

Comment: Have you tried using `<button>` instead of `<a>` for your close button?  That is what the current Bootstrap documentation uses: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples

Comment: @RobertC Yes I have but it still does not close and I tried using the close class as well and it still does not work. the '<a>' worked on the previous site just because I wanted to center the "button". And as I mentioned, the modal is not appearing any more. I know it is commented out in the code presented but it wasnt when I ran it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a syntax problem in your code:

```
$(function(){
  $('##myModal').modal('show');
}
```

This is incorrect; it should be:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

When corrected the Modal loads as a Modal, which in turn causes the Close button to operate as expected.  Absent this the modal still loads (because you have `in` activated) but loads absent the overlay and absent the hook to Bootstrap's Modal JS which explains why your close button is non-functional.

You can see a functional example here: http://www.bootply.com/24IPYP8O3F

**Why your code isn't working**

The `in` class on your Modal `div` instructs Bootstrap to make that modal visible, and position it according to the Bootstrap CSS.  Your jQuery is wrong though, so Bootstrap treats this like a bit of HTML that is just part of the document.

Once you correct your jQuery Bootstrap processes it as expected; as a Modal Javascript component.  Once that happens it is presented with the overlay (as default) and the `data-dismiss` attributes are processed correctly.

The short of it is that the entire issue for why your Modal is not behaving like a Modal is that your jQuery is wrong.

Comment: Yes, but for some reason in coldfusion, it does not like the '#' and when I put '##', the modal was appearing but the functionality was off. Also, are you talking about the following js files: bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js? if so, they are being called. Also, modal still loads? what do you mean

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/robontrix/jn2s61t3/1/#&togetherjs=IsMTPVcwfn

Comment: I will elaborate on why it is not working momentarily.  I have also added a Bootply example of the modal operating correctly.

Comment: Okay I understand so which is the correct jQuery file then? I thought I was using the correct js file: 1.7.1/jquery.min.js and  jquery.js

Comment: You misunderstand- your included files (jQuery.min, Bootstrap.min, etc) are perfectly fine.  It is the `$(function()` that you have written incorrectly.  Compare the two in my answer above.

Comment: Ohhhh.. Damn. Can't believe I miss that (embarrass look). Thank you for your help.